# WPF UI passing output from powershell function into textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I am creating a WPF UI and I am having trouble getting the output from a foreach loop within a function into a WPF textbox.  The variables I need to output ar $id $newValue and $serviceName

> #Iteration through services perform string replacement
> ForEach ($Response in $Responses ) {
> $id = $Response.id
> $newValue = $Response.value.Replace("\Service", "")
> $serviceName = $Response.serviceName
> Write-Output $id
> Write-Output $serviceName
> Write-Output $newValue
>
> ````
>         #if statement here for testing this should be removed 
>         if ($id -eq ) {
>
>             $Payload = @{
>
>                 hostName            = '';
>                 hostOperatingSystem = 0;
>                 optionalFilter1     = '';
>                 optionalFilter2     = '';
>                 description         = '';
>                 serviceName         = $serviceName;
>                 sectionName         = "Services";
>                 signature           = 'null';``
>                 value               = $newValue
>
>             } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
>
>             #Service Configuration API PUT method call to update fullpath value 
>             $newURI = $URI + '/' + $id
>             $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $newURI -Method PUT -Headers $Headers -Body $Payload -ContentType 'application/json'
>         }
>         #here for testing this should be removed
>         else {
>             $output.text =  "Nothing to do"
>         }
>
>     }
>     $output.text = "Done!" 
> }
>
> [xml]$Form = Get-Content "MainWindow.xaml"
> $NR = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
> $Win = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($NR)
>
> $URL = $win.FindName("URL")
> $cid = $win.FindName("Client_ID")
> $csecret = $win.FindName("Client_Secret")
> $update = $Win.FindName("Update")
> $output = $Win.FindName("output")
>
>
>
> $update.Add_Click( {
>         $UserAuthRoute = $URL.text
>         $client_id = $cid.text
>         $client_secret = $csecret.text
>         if ($UserAuthRoute -eq "" -or $client_secret -eq "" -or $client_secret -eq "") {
>             [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Please enter in all values","Variables Required")
>         }else{
>         UpdateServices $UserAuthRoute $client_id $client_secret
>         $output.text += "Service ID:"+$id , "Service Name: "+$serviceName, "$newValue"
>         }
>     })
>
> $Win.ShowDialog()    ```
> ````

Comment: If your UX/UI is WinForm or WPF, then it's not a console app. It's a bad UX/UI user experience to be bouncing from a GUI to a console. Keep the user in the GUI or just keep them in the console and skip the form stuff.  Why are you using Write-Output, which sends results to the console, when you say you want it in the form? You assign your code results to the .text property of a form element. Why are you using a default message box when you have a custom WPG UX/UI? Just focus your effort on providing all UX/UI in your WPF GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to append the value and separate with a newline

```
$output.text += "Service ID: " + $id + "`r`n" + "Service Name: " + $serviceName + "`r`n" + "Service Value: " + $newValue + "`r`n"
```